# CI build failed in case project reference is from another .net solution

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops, cicd

I have two independent .net projects. One is like a project which is baiscalliy to process invoice and another project is something which I am calling as common as I am keeping all sharable/reusable code under that.

Now any project can consume this common-project by adding it via add Existing project option so that source code will not move to consumer project which is Invoice management in my case.

Now if I add common project as reference and run my CI pipeline its failed as its not able to find the path of common project which is obvious as it may be different from my local machine to build server.
[image]

Now the solution that I am aware of are below :

1. Make common as Nuget package and use it under invoice management.
2. Build common project dll at some centralized file server and give that path in Invoice management
   for reference instead of absolute path.

Both solutions are not simple to implement  so I am looking for any better quick solution for the situation where project setup is like this and CI build has to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be actually reference via NuGet package. However, there is a third option which I do not recommend. You can use multiple repository pipeline. You will checkout there [two repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops). In thi case you have to mimic folder structure wich you will get on AzureDevops. Otherwise build will fail as it will not find the references.